# How to track position of columns on a DB table

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, orm

Okay, this is a little bit odd to explain, I'll try my best.

I have a `DB` table (`SQL`) called ***versions*** which contains a list of different **operations** that are part of a ***version***.

For example, **version 1.0:**

```
1. Insert XX

2. Delete YY

3. Insert XY
```

In my code, sometimes, it's needed to update the operations of an specific version. So, for example, let's say I need a new `Insert YX` in **position 2.**:

```
1. Insert XX

2. Insert YX

3. Delete YY

4. Insert XY
```

(This will still be version 1.0).

As you see, everytime I update the version some operations have their positions changed, so the initial tracking is lost. After numerous updates, it's nearly impossible the operations to be in the same place they initially were.

So, that's my problem. I need to track these columns **individually**:

I can't make any query looking for the position where "*Insert XX*" is, because **there could be more than one** `Insert XX` inside my table.

My question is, is there any solution to keep track of the position changes inside a SQL table?

I'm using PostgreSQL with Java as programming language and ORMLite as mapper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a unique id field for the row and a sequence field for the order

```
  id seq val
  1  1   Insert XX  
  2  2   Delete YY
  3  3   Insert XY
```

when you add the new item at pos 2 ( it gets next id(4), and you do an update where seq >=2 to set seq=sql+1 )

```
  id seq val
  1  1   Insert XX  
  4  2   Insert YX
  2  3   Delete YY
  3  4   Insert XY
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can never be sure of in a DB is the order of rows.  For example if you do:

```
insert *A* into myTable ...
insert *B* into myTable ...
```

And then do a

```
select * from myTable
```

You could end up with

```
A
B
```

or

```
B
A
```

Both are equally valid.  In your case you might want to add a column that has the specific purpose of ordering the results.  I typically use an integer and call it displayOrder.  So my select statement typically looks like:

select * from myTable order by displayOrder

One use of this is on a form where you can choose from several companies.  The one that I want at the top is in the middle alphabetically, so I can do an order by companyName.  Instead I use the displayOrder column.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll accept Ian's one for being the first. +1

Answer (score 1):

How about another table that lists the version number, the instruction number and the sequence number? It's getting more complicated but that also would allow you to recreate any version you needed. Plus you wouldn't have to keep rewriting the seq number in the main table.

```
Table Versions
     VersionID int,
     InstructionNum int,
     SeqNum int
```

where the VersionID is some version identifier (could be a string also). The InstructionNum points to a list of instructions (you already have that) and the the sequence number tells the order to do them.

This way you could also have instructions for a specific version that aren't in all versions.

Comment: thanks for this, but in my requeriments I don't want to add another table to the DB. +1